# Why does Apple require your passcode when you restart?

Tags: passwords, ios, iphone

On an iPhone or iPad, you can set up "Touch ID", which is a way to unlock your device using your fingerprint. I don't see why this wouldn't be much more secure than a passcode lock, as anyone can guess/see/know your passcode, while you cannot impersonate a fingerprint.

Yet, when you restart your phone, it requires your passcode instead of your fingerprint. This seems to suggest that it thinks your passcode is more secure than your fingerprint (as you have to use it to "unlock" touch ID). Why was this implemented, from a security point of view? Why do you have to enter your passcode when you restart your device?

Answer (score 8):

The reason for requiring passcode is because the file system encryption key is encrypted using the passcode:

> The content of a file is encrypted with a per-file key, which is wrapped with a class key and stored in a file’s metadata, which is in turn encrypted with the file system key. **The class key is protected with the hardware UID and, for some classes, the user’s passcode.** ([source](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf))

Why can't the file encryption key be stored by the fingerprint processor? Fingerprint cannot be used for for encryption/decryption due to the lossy nature of reading fingerprints.

While with the help of a secure coprocessor like the secure enclave, you can make fingerprint be usable for quick unlock mechanism, the security of such quick unlock depends on the coprocessor being able to discard the encryption key if the user/attacker entered the wrong fingerprint too many times. TouchID for example require entering regular passcode after five failed finger recognition.

If the system use only fingerprint unlock, that means that the coprocessor cannot ever discard the encryption key as that would permanently lock out the device, effectively opening up a trivial denial-of-service attack on the device.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is due to the Secure Enclave.

the "Secure Enclave" stores a mathematical representation of ones fingerprint in the phone however this enclave is also protected by your passcode.

When you get given the please enter your passcode at the start what apple is really doing is telling you to unlock your Secure Enclave as well as the SE locks down when a restart or update happens.

You can read about iOS security at:
https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

I guess from a security standpoint however it is better to lock the SE whenever power is completely off or a restart happens as other types of information are stored in the embedded SE. What's more I personally believe they do this to help people to remember their passcode but that's just speculation. Probably as well in case of damage to the iphone where the fingerprint scanner doesn't work?

Comment: A fingerprint is **not** more secure than a passcode (though perhaps a bit more than a few digits). A fingerprint is more like a username. It is something you _are_. Authentication should involve, at the very least, something you _are_, and something you _know_. Even a 5 digit passcode is not plastered all over every cup you've touched and every wall and table.

Comment: I would not disagree with you on that however with the smudges I see on peoples screens or how people are oblivious to who's around when writing their 4-6 digit pass code it's hard to feel that way. I believe though it's all up to the individual and throughout time hopefully authentication evolves to being able to clearly identify who you securely (Apple's facial recognition, biometric scanning) time will tell though but for now with the lack of education around you're probably right to a degree :)

Answer (score 0):

A fingerprint, or any biometrical measurement, is not a precise thing.  The device needs to compare a registered fingerprint with the measurement, and find out whether the measurement is "close enough".   As such, a fingerprint is not a cryptographic key.  If you change one single bit in a cryptographic key, it doesn't work any more.  So a biometric measurement can only be used to give you a permission or not, but cannot be used as a cryptographic key.  **Now, on an encrypted device, you need to give it the decryption key to let it decrypt itself, decryption key which it doesn't keep itself, by definition.**  This is simply impossible to provide with a biometric measurement, because it can never be reproducible up to a single bit.  You need a decryption key that is reproducible to the single bit and your fingerprint or face or whatever other biometric measurement cannot be used for that.  A pin code, however, is reproducible to the exact single bit.  **So it is not a matter of design choice, but of design impossibility that prompted Apple not to use your fingerprint to decrypt it.**  That's simply not a possibility.
When your iphone is switched off, the device *forgets* the clear text of certain cryptographic keys, and only knows their encrypted versions which are encrypted with your pin code.  Without the pin code, no matter how, the phone CAN'T access the cryptographic keys in clear form, which it NEEDS to decrypt files on the phone.  The pin code is a precise cryptographic key itself.  If one would replace the pin code by the biometric fingerprint measurement, there is little chance that you will be able to produce *exactly* the same fingerprint measurement upon startup, and without that EXACT same key, the phone wouldn't be able to decrypt the keys.

Comment: This doesn't add anything not already covered by the existing answers.

Comment: @twisty: It wasn't clear to me that the given answers already pointed out that it is not a matter of choice of design by Apple, but that it is simply *impossible* to use any biometric measurement to *decrypt* something.  That's simply an impossible design, and this impossibility is the essence of the answer.  The phrase in a previous answer that comes closest, is "Why can't the file encryption key be stored by the fingerprint processor? Fingerprint cannot be used for for encryption/decryption due to the lossy nature of reading fingerprints. " but it was not the core or Lie's answer.

Comment: That didn't jump out at me as I read your post. Consider an [edit] to draw that out more clearly.

Comment: I edited the text to put more emphasis on this point